# "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpEntity

Tags: java, apache, http

I'm trying to use the apache http library in my project. I imported the libreries in my project https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cm9ck.jpg

When I run my program, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpEntity
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.HttpEntity
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 6 more
```

Comment: Did you use a build tool to make sure you fetched all necessary transitive dependencies?

Answer (score 5):

The ClassLoader can't find org.apache.http.HttpEntity, which should be inside "httpcore-4.3.jar".  Open the jar as an archive and verify that it contains org/apache/http/HttpEntity.class.  If it does, the issue is in your launch configuration.  In Eclipse, go to Run > Run Configurations... and find the Java Application profile for your main class (which should be the class containing the main method in "Launcher" project, based on the screenshot).  Under the Classpath tab, you should see your library jars listed.

If not, go back to your "Launcher" project in the Navigation pane, right-click and select Properties, go to "Build Path", remove your jars, press OK, then go back in and add them again (to guarantee the eclipse meta-data is fresh).  Also, under the "Order and Export" tab, it's a good idea to check off all jars so that if you include Launcher as a dependency for another project, the jars are transitively included.

Answer (score 1):

your Eclipse is having trouble locating the external jars, try importing them into your workspace or referencing them outside by using "add external jar's"

Answer (score 0):

In my case Maven was not updating dependencies properly. I use mvn clean and then re-updated dependencies then it got fixed.