# ClassNotFoundException for HttpClient class

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Apache HTTPClient to make HTTP requests. My code compiles, but I get this error during runtime:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.HttpEntity
```

This missing class is part of HTTPClient's httpcore, which I have included in my referenced libraries. I checked to make sure HttpEntity is in there, and it definitely is.

I am using Eclipse as my IDE. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe this question is related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469624/main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-http-httpentity

Comment: @Stilzk1n Thank you, but I have read all the related questions and nothing has helped me. Based on the top answer there my issue is the launch configuration. When I open Run Configurations, "Maven Dependencies" is listed there, which should imply that httpcore is in there.